# split or explode polygon into segments in geopandas or related library

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to get the individual line segments of a polygon. I want to work with each segment individually, such as get the length, get the vertices etc.

So I have a pandas geodataframe `gdf`

I can access the polygon through gdf.geometry

The following accesses the polygon as a linestring

```
for polygon in gdf.geometry:
    boundary = polygon.boundary
    print(boundary)
```

Adding `.length()` gets me the total length.

Any ideas how to split or explode out each line segment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I understand that you are looking for series of pairs of **Point** as **LineString** that form the boundary of **Polygon** or **MultiPolygon**
- have used Belgium and UK as sample polygons
- solution is around discipline of using geometry **iterators**

  - for **MultiPolygon** it is **geoms**
  - for **exterior** which are **LineArray** it is **coords**
  - for pairs of co-ordinates use `zip()` technique to get pairs to reform a two point **LineString**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

# pick a polygon and multipolygon to create line segments from
gdf = world.loc[world["iso_a3"].isin(["BEL", "GBR"])]


line_segs = gpd.GeoSeries(
    gdf["geometry"]
    .apply(
        lambda g: [g]
        if isinstance(g, shapely.geometry.Polygon)
        else [p for p in g.geoms]
    )
    .apply(
        lambda l: [
            shapely.geometry.LineString([c1, c2])
            for p in l
            for c1, c2 in zip(p.exterior.coords, list(p.exterior.coords)[1:])
        ]
    )
    .explode()
)

# visualise it's works...
line_segs.plot()
# output for SO
print(line_segs.to_frame().head(10).to_markdown())
```

#### sample output data

|  | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 129 | LINESTRING (6.15665815595878 50.80372101501058, 6.043073357781111 50.12805166279423) |
| 129 | LINESTRING (6.043073357781111 50.12805166279423, 5.782417433300907 50.09032786722122) |
| 129 | LINESTRING (5.782417433300907 50.09032786722122, 5.674051954784829 49.5294835475575) |
| 129 | LINESTRING (5.674051954784829 49.5294835475575, 4.799221632515724 49.98537303323637) |
| 129 | LINESTRING (4.799221632515724 49.98537303323637, 4.286022983425084 49.90749664977255) |
| 129 | LINESTRING (4.286022983425084 49.90749664977255, 3.588184441755658 50.37899241800356) |
| 129 | LINESTRING (3.588184441755658 50.37899241800356, 3.123251580425688 50.78036326761455) |
| 129 | LINESTRING (3.123251580425688 50.78036326761455, 2.658422071960274 50.79684804951575) |
| 129 | LINESTRING (2.658422071960274 50.79684804951575, 2.513573032246143 51.14850617126183) |
| 129 | LINESTRING (2.513573032246143 51.14850617126183, 3.314971144228537 51.34578095153609) |

#### visualize

[image]

#### join polygon attributes to line segments

- indexes on *GeoSeries* and *GeoDataFrame* are the same
- hence simple join allows attributes of polygon to be joined to line segments

```
line_segs.to_frame().join(gdf.drop(columns="geometry"))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, one small addition, how would you append the `iso_a3` value to the `line_segs` dataframe as a separate column, this will be a duplicate number across several rows related to the former index value which this retains?

Comment: updated answer - simple case of `join()`